# How to calculate LF/HF power ratio from heart rate RR-intervals

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum

I've been searching everywhere, but I'm having trouble finding a step-by-step guide for someone with little knowledge of signal processing.

I have a file with a list of RR-intervals in milliseconds. The RR-interval is the time between successive heartbeats, so if you took the cumulative sum, you could think of it as a timestamp for each heart beat.

One method of calculating heart rate variability is to find the ratio of power between the low frequency band (0.04 - 0.15 Hz) and the high frequency band (0.15 - 0.40 Hz) in the heart rate signal.

How can I find these values? The RR-intervals aren't like an evenly sampled signal, so I think resampling would be involved. Thank you very much.

Comment: How to calculate LF/HF power ratio from heart rate RR-intervals? I have data like Time, Pulse Rate, RR Intervall. But i want to calculate LF, HF and Ratio LF/HF. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link with a bunch of stuff relating to HVR and how to calculate various features using python [discrete-heart-rate-signal-using-python-part-1](http://www.paulvangent.com/2016/03/15/analyzing-a-discrete-heart-rate-signal-using-python-part-1/). Hope it helps.